# using Typesafe Activator on Windows

Tags: typesafe, typesafe-activator

I tried to run the hello-slick template from inside Typesafe Activator.
When it recompiled it produced:

```
Refreshing list of source files to watch for changes...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Edward G Prentice\.sbt\plugins\project
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Edward G Prentice\.sbt\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Edward G Prentice\hello-slick\project
[info] Set current project to hello-slick (in build file:/C:/Users/Edward%20G%20Prentice/hello-slick/)
[error] Expected '"'
[error] apply -cp "C:/Users/Edward
[error] ^
Failed to reload source file list: sbt process never got in touch, so unable to handle request WatchTransitiveSourcesRequest(true)
```

so clearly it is not expecting spaces in that portion of the classpath. I understand what's failing but not how to fix it.

...and what is the best channel to resolve problems with Typesafe Activator?

Comment: This is due to a bug in how Activator deals with spaces in paths.  What version did you use?

Comment: I don't remember now which version. That was two months ago. Thanks for checking in.